# Add cell dingbat to cell, to display using DisplayForm

Tags: formatting, cells

I'm programically constructing a palette, and trying to add items/cells to the palette with a dingbat.  The cells themselves have a style of `"Item"` which should show up with the dingbat, but when adding the cell to the palette via `DisplayForm[cell]`, the dingbat doesn't show.

```
OpenerView[{"Definitions", Column[(DisplayForm[#])&/@definitions]}]
```

@definitions is a list of full form `Cell` expressions, with a style of Item.
I've tried manipulating the cell with `CellStyle`, `Style`, and other techniques before adding the cell to the palette, with no luck.

For instance:

```
 definitions = {Cell[TextData[{"A ", StyleBox["unit vector", FontWeight -> "Bold"],
   " is a vector that has a magnitude of 1, with no units."}], "Item",
   CellChangeTimes -> {{3.726004891*10^9, 3.726004913*10^9}},
   CellTags -> "definition"]};
```

After trial and error, I was able to prepend a dingbat to the text in the cell like

```
PrependTo[cell[[1,1]], StyleBox["\[FilledSquare] ", Red]];
```

But it would be nice to know how to do it using a `CellDingbat`.

Comment: Could you provide the code for a few `definitions`?

Comment: Thanks bbodfrey, I'm pulling the definitions from another notebook, but basically, they are all mostly like this.

    
Cell[TextData[{"A ", StyleBox["unit vector", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
   " is a vector that has a magnitude of 1, with no units."}], "Item",
  CellChangeTimes -> {{3.726004891*10^9, 3.726004913*10^9}}, 
 CellTags -> "definition"]
    

After trial and error, I was able to prepend a dingbat to the text in the cell  like
    PrependTo[cell[[1,1]], StyleBox["\[FilledSquare] ", Red]];
, but it would be nice to know how to do it using a CellDingbat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options make more sense when the `Cell` is in the list of `Cells` of a `Notebook[{cell1, cell2,...}]` and less sense when the cell is an inline cell as in the OP's use.  For instance `CellMargins` is one these.  Apparently `CellDingbat` is also.  Just adding `CellDingbat -> StyleBox["\[FilledSquare]", Red]` manually to the cell can confirm this.  One can see that the `CellDingbat` is in the output cell by selecting the cell and using the menu command Cell > Show Expression.  One can also see that the dingbat is not displayed.  One might go further and map `CellPrint /@ definitions` (after adding `CellDingbat`, of course) to see that the dingbat is displayed in this form.

From this I infer that the `CellDingbat` option is ignored when displaying an inline cell.  I cannot find documentation to confirm this, though.